# Mantener la imagen fija cuando cambia la orientación del móvil

Tags: javascript, ios, swift, programación-móvil

Hola a todos estoy intentando de hacer esto effecto que he visto solo en codigo swift... utiliza el gyroscope, en esto enlace se puede ver el codigo swift:

http://nshipster.com/cmdevicemotion/

Me gustaría hacerlo en Javascript, algun me puede ayudar??

[image: Rotation with gravity]

Gracias

Comment: Si lo solucionas por favor comentar la solucion! Me parece muy interesante esto :D Saludos!

Answer (score 4):

Lo puedes *conseguir parecido* con [Detecting device orientation](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Detecting_device_orientation).

Según la documentación:

> Aún está en la fase experimental
>
> ---
>
> Chrome y Firefox no manejan los ángulos de la misma manera,
>     por lo que en algunos ejes de la dirección se invierte.

---

Todo lo que necesitas para comenzar es detectar los cambios de orientación  del dispositivo:

```
window.addEventListener("deviceorientation", handleOrientation, true);
```

Después de detectar los eventos (en este caso la función `handleOrientation()`), actualiza de forma periódica los cambios de orientación.

El evento de orientación contiene cuatro valores:

- [DeviceOrientationEvent.absolute](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/DeviceOrientationEvent/absolute)
- [DeviceOrientationEvent.alpha](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/DeviceOrientationEvent/alpha)
- [DeviceOrientationEvent.beta](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/DeviceOrientationEvent/beta)
- [DeviceOrientationEvent.gamma](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/DeviceOrientationEvent/gamma)

---

```
function handleOrientation(event) {

    var absolute = event.absolute;
    var alpha    = event.alpha; // eje-z - de    0 a -360 grados
    var beta     = event.beta;  // eje-x - de -180 a  180 grados
    var gamma    = event.gamma; // eje-y - de  -90 a   90 grados    
}
```

---

El siguiente código lo he probado en un:

`iPhone 6S (v10.0.2)`, en los navegadores `Safari (v10.0)` y `Chrome (v54.0)`

**[Ver Demo](https://jsbin.com/fexeqe)**

```
if (window.DeviceMotionEvent) {

    window.addEventListener('deviceorientation', function (e) {

        var alpha = e.alpha;
        handleOrientation(alpha);
    }, true);

} else { 

    alert('Tu dispositivo no es compatible');
}

function handleOrientation(alpha) {

    var a = Math.round(alpha);
    rotate(a);
}

function rotate(degree) {
    $('.image').css({
        '-webkit-transform': 'rotate(' + degree + 'deg)',
        '-moz-transform':    'rotate(' + degree + 'deg)',
        '-ms-transform':     'rotate(' + degree + 'deg)',
        '-o-transform':      'rotate(' + degree + 'deg)',
        'transform':         'rotate(' + degree + 'deg)'
    });
}
```

Comment: Muchas gracias Hombre!!
Que dios te lo pague con muchos hijos!!

Comment: Todo menos hijos...por favor :) Es muy interesante la verdad... a ver si lo puede perfeccionar estos días ;)

Comment: pruebo! muchas gracias